# stop socket from waiting to ack

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, websocket, tcpserver

I am writing a TCP server in Python.
I want the server to close the connection right after the server send the SYN-ACK (response to SYN from client) without waiting to the client's ACK response (without finishing the handshake).

That's my server:

```
def get_tcp(port, data_len=1024):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind(('', port))
    sock.listen(1)

    conn, addr = sock.accept()

    conn.close()
```

Is there a way to do it?

Thank you very much

Comment: What is the problem are you trying to solve by this? Let's avoid [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: My client is spoofing it's IP.
So the TCP handshake can't really finish.